# Complex-linear matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I'm reading Tapp's introduction to matrix groups.The book introduced complex-linear matrices and it gives this characterization of complex-linear matrix:

Let $B\in M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$, let $J$ be the matrix

$J = \left (\begin{array}{}
0 & -I \\
I  & 0
\end{array}\right )$,
where $I$ is the identity matrix ,  B is complex linear if and only if $BJ=JB$.

I understand why if $B$ is a complex-linear the $BJ=JB$ (by
using a commutative diagram) but i don't understand how i can prove 
the other side (if $BJ=JB$ then $B$ is complex-linear).

Is it enough to say that if $B$ commutes with $i$ ($J$ is "the copy of $i$" in $M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$) then $B$ is linear complex ?
Do you have any hints to give me for the proof? Thank you all.

{Note}: Definition of complex linear matrix: B is a complex linear iff  B is in the image of a map  $\rho_n: M_n(\mathbb C) \to M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ . This map associates to each matrix $(X + iY)$ a matrix  $\left (\begin{array}{}
X & -Y \\
Y & X
\end{array}\right)$ , $X,Y \in  M_n(\mathbb R)$

Comment: Write an arbitrary matrix $B$ in block form and make a direct computation.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on David Hill's comment: suppose that
$$B = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
X & Y \\
Z & W
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Notice that $BJ = JB$ if and only if 
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix} 
Y & -X \\
W & -Z
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
-Z & -W \\
X & Y
\end{bmatrix},$$
which holds if and only if $X=W$ and $Z=-Y$, i.e., if and only if 
$$B = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
X & Y \\
-Y & X
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Also, note that the [definition of $\rho_n$](https://books.google.com/books?id=BjD-CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q&f=false) you state above is different than that stated in Tapp's book: 
[image]

In this case, 
$$J_n := 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
& & \ddots \\
& & & \\
& & & & 0 & -1 \\
& & & & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \in M_{2n} (\mathbb{R}).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much ... Now it's all clear to me .. You have been very kind and  very accurate.
In fact the definition on Tapp's book is just what you write ... I mistakenly report that of an another text on the same subject.
sorry David Hill, I don't understand what you write .. I was reading hastily.

Thanks again to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

More in line with Tapp's book, he notices (I use the same notations as Tapp) that it suffices to show that $F(iX)=iF(X)$, with $F=f_n^{-1}\circ R_{B}\circ f_{n}$. Also, $J_{2n}^{2}=-I$ so $BJ_{2n}=J_{2n}B$ implies $B=-J_{2n}BJ_{2n}$. Thus $F=f_n^{-1}\circ R_{-J_{2n}BJ_{2n}}\circ f_{n}=-f_n^{-1}\circ R_{J_{2n}} \circ R_B \circ R_{J_{2n}} \circ f_n$. Now, the point of $J_{2n}$ is that $ R_{J_{2n}} \circ f_n=f_n \circ R_{iI} $ so also, $f_n^{-1}\circ R_{J_{2n}} = R_{iI}\circ f_n^{-1} $. So, we get $F(iX)=-R_{iI}\circ f_n^{-1} \circ R_B\circ f_n \circ R_{iI} (iX)=-R_{iI}\circ f_n^{-1} \circ R_B\circ f_n (-X)=-R_{iI}\circ F(-X)$

Now, $F$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear (as Tapp points out), so $F(iX)=R_{iI}(F(X))=iF(X)$